# Is it bad practice to dynamically create a variable from array to read a $_GET method in php

Tags: php, arrays, get, dynamic-variables

Going through a php class file at work I found an interesting snippet. The script is dynamically creating a variable, dynamically checking if there is an active $_GET[''] for the variable it's creating and if there is it's loading the $_GET data and if it's not it's writing N/A to the variable that it's dynamically creating. The script then continues on to a switch function with the same logic for it's case breaks.

1.) Is this safe?

2.) Can it be attacked?

3.) Is there an easier way to do this?

4.) Why would you do this?

```
$switch_types = array("id","type","page");

foreach ($switch_types as $key => $value) {
    $$value = $value;
    if(isset($_GET[$$value])){
        $$value = $_GET[$$value];
        }
    else{
        $$value = "N/A";
    }        
}
```

Comment: In terms of safety I don't think this in itself is a risk, that all depends on what you do with the variables once they are populated with the contents of the query string

Comment: Depends on where it's used. It's mainly a long-winded variant of [`extract`](http://php.net/extract)+[`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key). ("Bad practice" and "safe?" make this question too broad without further details.)

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of dynamically creating variables like this ... with extract or ... having register globals turned on ... if I was to search your code for `$page` I wouldn't be able to find it

Comment: @mario Does this help with being to broad? Safe: Is this something that can be broken by user input? Bad practice: If this is Safe can it be written a simplified function or is there already an existing function that does what the snippet is currently doing.

Comment: The snippet itself is harmless. Variables itself can't cause trouble. It still depends on how they're used afterwards. Localizing things for readability is sometimes beneficial, othertimes not as much. -- I'd personally replace it with something like just `extract($_GET->multi->text["id,type,page"]);` instead. (You can't use that).

Comment: @mario thank you. The data is later sanitized with and pushed into a stored procedure. I haven't had any introduction to dynamic variable creation with arrays and as such I wanted to ensure that what I was seeing would be a safe approach if I need to do it in the future.

Comment: This would be bad if it created variables for any `$_GET` parameters. But because it only does it for the specific list in `$switch_types`, it's not a problem. This is just a DRY way of writing `$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'N/A';` and similarly for the other variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically just a long-winded way to write:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'N/A';
$type = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : 'N/A';
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'N/A';
```

It's perfectly safe because the list of variables to assign is specified in the program, it doesn't come dynamically from the client.

There's some unnecessary code in his loop -- `$$value = $value` is not needed. It can be simplified to:

```
foreach ($switch_types as $value) {
    if(isset($_GET[$value])){
        $$value = $_GET[$value];
        }
    else{
        $$value = "N/A";
    }        
}
```

or:

```
foreach ($switch_types as $value) {
    $$value = isset($_GET[$value]) ? $_GET[$value] : 'N/A';
}
```